# ScrollView Refresh control is not visible when reload content from scrollview bottom

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have a scrollview which content is larger than phone screen.
I scroll to the bottom and there I have function that reload content of that scrollview but first clear data source for it.
Reload function is connected to `RefreshControl` on scrollview.
But `RefreshControl` is not visible while loading data except when I slightly touch screen where content should be.
And this is only when I start reload from scrollview bottom.
I tried to scroll to top but it doesn't solve it:

```
onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
   this.scrollView.scrollTo({ y: 0 });
}}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

```
<ScrollView
        ref={ref => (this.scrollView = ref)}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.props.getDataInProgress}
            onRefresh={this.reloadData.bind(this)}
          />
        }
      >
  {this.renderData()}

renderData() {
  return this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
        return ... some function that return other components
```

So as I wrote if I pull down loader is visible.
But if I scroll to bottom and click one some button that call same function as pull to refresh loader is not visible.
[EXAMPLE](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/90494/56068873-53ace380-5d35-11e9-9e52-18c639d1e575.gif)

Comment: Please add the code for `ScrollView` component to show how it's configured.

Comment: Is your `this.props.getDataInProgress` value changing when you call your reload funtion?

Comment: Yes. It’s set to true when I clear scrollview source and false when I load them. Seems that when I set source to [] something is wrong with height and that is why loader is not visible but can’t figue how to solve it.

Comment: Since you are emptying data, the child views inside `ScrollView` will not exist, and since the `ScrollView` doesn't have hieght, it disappears, also removing the refresh control. Try giving your `ScrollView` full size of screen or container using `flex:1`

Comment: No. I tried flex, flexGrow nothing works. I attached image with similar thing.
What I notices in function that reload content before call I put `this.scrollview.scrollTo({y: 0})` but then RefreshControl is not on top. It's sometimes at the screen middle sometimes above middle depend on how much I scrolled down and call reload action.